# Why would cleos wallet list fail?

Tags: cleos

I get this strange behaviour -

```
 cleos wallet create -n trevoro
```

Error 3120001: Wallet already exists Try to use

> different wallet name.

```
cleos wallet list
```

> Wallets: []

I cannot get trevoro in the list but it says already there. Any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `cleos wallet open` before listing wallets.

Comment: This worked - trevor@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-lon1-01:~/eos/Docker/dev$ cleos wallet open -n trevoro
Opened: trevoro
trevor@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-lon1-01:~/eos/Docker/dev$ cleos wallet list